# Converting InfoPath list-form into admin-approved form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I created a custom InfoPath list-form, added all the controls, created all the rules etc. and now it seems I'll have to add some code-behind into it. Is there any way to convert the template type or at least copy all the things I've got into the new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to switch between templates , you can check this link for more information 
: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52675/infopath-2010-sharepoint-liist-form-and-custom-code

However you can copy InfoPath controls from one form template to another but only if the control contains data that is a part of a view, here's how :

- just copy the control from your template
- paste it in the other template using " keep the source formatting " option
- then bind the control to a field

check this link for more details : 
http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2010/videos/copy-control-one-infopath-form-template-another.htm

for copying the rules i don't think there is an easy way to do it but here's how :

- Save your InfoPath from as source files (File > Save as Source Files)
- Close the form and use a text editor to view the XML in manifest.xsf
- Find the name of the rules you want to copy, copy and paste them in the new form
- Save the file and open into design mode. You rules should now be copied

for more information check this link: http://devspoint.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/copy-infopath-rules/